# How to handle properly concurency excpetion and expose it via Service Stack?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, servicestack

In my app i expose some functionalities via rest api (using service stack but it is not really important).
Currently i'm wondering which is the best way to expose `concurency exception` issue received from repository layer. Scenario:
Someone wants to get some data from my api e.g :

```
api/orders/1
```

The problem is that meanwhile someone else deleted order with given id.
`Entity Framework` throws `concurency exception`, i'm able to catch it in the api layer but what should i return? Some unusual http error or something? Or maybe there is a good practice to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

You can register a [Custom Exception Mapping](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#custom-exceptions) to map C# Exceptions to HTTP Status Codes, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
    MapExceptionToStatusCode = {
        { typeof(CustomInvalidRoleException), 403 },
        { typeof(CustomerNotFoundException), 404 },
    }
});
```

If the Order no longer exists you can return a `404 NotFound` to indicate the entity no longer exists. For other conflicts you can return a `409 Conflict` to indicate there was a conflict with the current state of the entity, otherwise a general `400 Bad Request` is suitable if you don't expect consumers to take specific action and replay the request to resolve the conflict on their side.